# Refer the target's Preprocessor macro within a pod project

Tags: cocoapods, podspec, podfile, post-install

> I have a project that has multiple targets.  On each target's, I have
>   added some pre-processor macros. It has multiple pods added to the
>   workspace. Obviously, the target's preprocessor macro won't be visible
>   to the pod projects. How can I get that done?

1) I tried using the `post_install` and tried to get the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`  from the target and copy it to pod project.
But not able to figure out how to do that.

2) Also is there a way this can be specified in the `podspec` of the pod so that way integration can be seamless.